# istanbul and Circle-CI

Tags: istanbul, circleci

I'm running istanbul and getting the report ok, I have created a post command in circle to run it and I get no errors, How can I configure the output directory or a post task to copy the output to a folder from which Circle can pick it up automatically?

Thanks! Guillermo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see my example circle.yml for a nodejs project.

https://gist.github.com/archit/8735d1edc3e3cbfc5991